# How to store Color code values in local storage?

Tags: android, hex, textcolor

I am working on a Theme app, which will change the font colour of the app. I am storing the colour hex code values in offline and retrieving but while retrieving it's coming blank.

I am storing through Realm Database.

```
RealmManager.getInstance(this);
realm = RealmManager.getRealm();

realm.beginTransaction();

theme = realm.createObject(Theme.class);
theme.setFontColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
realm.commitTransaction();

textColor = theme.getTextColor();
viewHolder.textTitle.setTextColor(textColor);
```

Code of Theme Class

```
public class Theme extends RealmObject {
  private int id;
  private int textColor;

  public int getId() {
     return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
     this.id = id;
  }
  public int getTextColor() {
      return textColor;
  }
  public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
     this.textColor = textColor;
  }
}
```

Please kindly go through my post and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Please post the code for the Theme class.

Comment: hey i have update my post with Theme class please check